# C# String missing characters in WindowsForm App

Tags: c#, string, csv, listview, encoding

I'm building a network scan utility app and I'm encountering some issues while displaying string in a listview.

I'm finding the Netbios name of a local remote machine through socket request and bytes encoding, when I display the result in a listview the domain name doesn't show at all but when I export the text of that listview row subitem that contains the NetBios name of the machine in a .csv file it shows correctly the entire string like this "COMPUTER1-WORKGROUP" for example when in the listview it will display only "COMPUTER1".

Here you can see the display in the listview in the windows application :

[image]

As you can see in the "Nom Netbios" column in the first row it only display "NVRSERVEUR"

And then when I take the ListViewItem.SubItem.Text and write it in a .csv file, as we can see in the image below it displays "NVRSERVEUR-IRIS" which IRIS stands for the network domain name.

[image]

Here is the code of the task that I use for retrieving the netbios computer name and network domain name :

```
static Task<NetworkInfosWrapper> getNetBiosNameAsyncReply(PingReply reply)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<NetworkInfosWrapper>();
        byte[] receiveBuffer = new byte[1024];
        Socket requestSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        requestSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReceiveTimeout, 100);
        EndPoint remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(reply.Address.ToString()), 137);
        IPEndPoint originEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        requestSocket.Bind(originEndPoint);
        SocketAsyncEventArgs e = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
        e.SetBuffer(NameRequest, e.Offset, NameRequest.Count());
        e.RemoteEndPoint = remoteEndPoint;
        e.Completed += (obj, sender) =>
        {
            try
            {
                int receivedByteCount = requestSocket.ReceiveFrom(receiveBuffer, ref remoteEndPoint);
                if (receivedByteCount >= 90)
                {
                    Encoding enc = new UTF8Encoding();
                    //Encoding enc = new ASCIIEncoding();

                    string deviceName = enc.GetString(receiveBuffer, 57, 16).Trim();
                    string networkName = enc.GetString(receiveBuffer, 75, 16).Trim();

                    tcs.SetResult(new NetworkInfosWrapper(reply,(deviceName.Trim()+" - "+networkName.Trim()).Replace(" ", "")));

                }
                else
                {
                    tcs.SetResult(new NetworkInfosWrapper(reply, "N/A"));
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                tcs.SetResult(new NetworkInfosWrapper(reply, "N/A"));
            }

        };
        requestSocket.SendToAsync(e);
        return tcs.Task;
    }
```

Here is how I display it in the listview in the main scan function :

```
foreach (var netbiosTask in netbiosTasks)
        {
            if (netbiosTask.Result.reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                ListViewItem lvi;
                addr = IPAddress.Parse(netbiosTask.Result.reply.Address.ToString());
                string mac = ScanUtils.getMacByIp(netbiosTask.Result.reply.Address.ToString());

                lvi = new ListViewItem(ScanUtils.GetReverseDNS(netbiosTask.Result.reply.Address.ToString(),1000));
                lvi.SubItems.Add(netbiosTask.Result.reply.Address.ToString());
                lvi.SubItems.Add("UP");
                lvi.SubItems.Add(netbiosTask.Result.reply.RoundtripTime.ToString() + " ms");
                lvi.SubItems.Add(netbiosTask.Result.netBiosName);
                lvi.SubItems.Add(mac);
                lvi.SubItems.Add(ScanUtils.getMacvendor(mac));
                listView.Items.Add(lvi);
                if(progressBar1.Value < progressBar1.Maximum) {
                    progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Value + 1;
                }
                if (!mStopThread)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is how I export the content of the listview as a .csv file :

```
private void enregistrerBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StringBuilder csvContent = new StringBuilder();
        csvContent.AppendLine("sep=;");
        csvContent.AppendLine("Hostname;Adresse IP;Netbios;Adresse Mac;Mac Vendor");

        foreach (ListViewItem item in listView.Items)
        {
            csvContent.AppendLine(string.Format("{0};{1};{2};{3};{4}", item.SubItems[0].Text, item.SubItems[1].Text, item.SubItems[4].Text, item.SubItems[5].Text, item.SubItems[6].Text));
        }

        string csvPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory).ToString() + @"\Resources\networkScan"+ DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm-ss") +".csv";

        File.AppendAllText(csvPath, csvContent.ToString(),Encoding.UTF8);
    }
```

I've tried to use both ASCII and UTF-8 encoding for the csv write and socket response's bytes encoding.
  Any one else ever encountered this kind of issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Trim` does not remove null bytes from the string by default, only whitespace characters. Apply `Trim` specifically to remove null bytes like this:

```
string deviceName = enc.GetString(receiveBuffer, 57, 16).Trim('\0');
string networkName = enc.GetString(receiveBuffer, 75, 16).Trim('\0');
```

Whether you see the part of the string after null bytes depends on how you display them. The listview stops printing text when it sees a null byte, the editor you use to look at the CSV file (Excel?) seems to be able to continue after null bytes.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I've just tried it and indeed it works ! I'm not very experienced and idk if I could have found this by my self ! I use Excel yes and I was very confused by this, now i understand thanks for the explanation. Cheers

Comment: Now I could use some more help because for some devices's network domain names I have unknown characters displaying like this : https://imgur.com/qMKsAlr , Do you know how can i get rid of these if it detects some unknow characters, or maybe translate them better ? Thanks

Comment: Try the `TrimFromZero` function from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403524/c-sharp-trimming-string-from-first-null-terminator-and-onwards)

Comment: If this does not work, it is possible that the NetBIOS protocol does not use null to determine the end of the string. Maybe the protocol sends the actual length of the string somewhere with the reply?

Comment: Well I tried to get it working but with no result yet, it doesn't change anything for now ! I'll try to dig deeper on your reasoning you are probably right, I'll give you some feedback soon :) Thanks a lot man you are da real mvp !